Trouble Migrating CiviCRM From WordPress to Drupal
I am volunteering on a project to help a small nonprofit move their CiviCRM database from WordPress to Drupal.  I think I am close but I am running into an issue after CiviCRM is installed.
I have installed CiviCRM and switched the database to my database from WordPress. I cleared the civicrm_uf_match based on this post. I also used cv to clear the cache.
When trying to access CiviCRM I get the error " CRM_Core_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in civicrm_api3() (line 135 of /home/user/public_html/folder/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/api/api.php)."
Based on a recommendation from @Coleman I enabled backtrace. I have not needed to do this in years so I very much appreciate the recommendation.
If I look at the log files created it has hundreds if not thousands debug messages but does not appear to have any errors.
I am not sure where to go from here and would appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Steve

That error message isn't very specific. You might get a better one if you enable debug and backtrace settings.

@Coleman, thank you for getting back to me. I turned on CIVICRM_DEBUG_LOG_QUERY in the civicrm.settings.php. I hope this was the right thing. I generally would turn on "debugging" and backtracking at /civicrm/admin/setting/debug but I do not have a working copy of this installation to get to this page. I did not get any errors the way I did.  If you have any further ideas I would appreciate it.
